# Motto meaning: Whenever you are, we're already then

Tags: meaning-in-context

I wondering about meaning of The Echo Park Time Travel Mart's motto. Which is:

> Whenever you are, we're already then.

The Mart is selling funny things, so I could guess it a little bit, but not quite.

Comment: It's just a "time-based" variation of *Whatever you want, we've got it*. It's a  weird concept to express *(Whenever you are in need of something we can supply, we will already have it for you)*, so that matches the quirky / non-grammatical slogan format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it must be a pun based on the expression "Wherever you go, you're already there" or perhaps "Wherever you go, there you are".

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly a pun with the meaning "When you are only going to (do something ) we are already there (ready to help)